# Covariance matrix of a random vector?

Tags: probability, matrices, covariance

$\newcommand{\cov}{\mathrm{cov}}$ I'd like to ask a question similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1541464/348586). The question I've linked to is about $X = (X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n)^T$, a random vector in $\Bbb R^n$ and $A$, an $m \times n$ matrix. sebastianross asks how to find the covariance matrix of $AX$.

I'd like to ask about the covariance matrix of $2(\mathbf{b} + X^TB)$ where $\mathbf{b} \in \Bbb R^m$ and $B$ is an $n\times m$ matrix.

Imitating [the answer to the question I've linked to](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1545731/348586),

$$\begin{aligned} \cov(X^TB) &= \mathbb{E} \left( (X^TB)(X^TB)^T \right) - \mathbb{E}(X^TB)\mathbb{E}(X^TB)^T \\ &= \mathbb{E}((X^TB)B^TX) - \mathbb{E}(X^T)B\mathbb{E}(B^TX) \\ &= \mathbb{E}((X^TB)B^TX) - \mathbb{E}(X^T)BB^T\mathbb{E}(X) \end{aligned} $$

(I'm leaving out the multiplication by $2$ and $\mathbf{b}$, although I'd like to go further at some point.)

So here, the common factor, $BB^T$, lies in the middle of the matrix products. What would you do next?

Comment: Using both $B$ and $b$ is kind of a bad idea

Comment: Before you start you should clarify what $X^\top$ is to you. A row vector or a column vector? In any case: a covariance matrix is always the expectation of column vector matrix multiplied by the row vector. Otherwise you get a single number, not a matrix.

Comment: $4E(X^TBB^TX)$ is the right answer, you cannot do better, and your last formula is not correct since $X$ and $X^T$ are not independent.